# Migrating My Sites to new dedicated site host

Tags: 2007, my-site, migration, powershell

We have taken over a site where My Sites are placed in the Intranet web application.

I want to migrate the My Sites to a dedicated host site.

From what i have been able to find out so far, I will need to do an STSADM -o backup of each personal site and restore it into the new content database.

I will be automating this process using PowerShell.

Has anyone tried this?

Any caveats i need to be aware of?

Since i need to move site collections out of an existing content database into another, as far as i can see i cannot use a simple SSP migration.

Any help appreciated :-)

EDIT:
I wrote a blog post on how I solved this using stsadm mergecontentdbs [here](http://andersrask.spoint.me/2010/05/20/moving-my-sites-to-a-seperate-web-application/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using stsadm -o mergecontentdbs to move them all into a single content database and then attaching that content database to the new site host? I don't know for certain that this will work, but it seems like it would make the process much simpler and with less risk of data loss as the sites will still be available.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I guess one thing to remember would be that it would only work if all the My Sites would fit into a single content DB (e.g. less than 100GB or whatever 'threshold' is being used) using quota x number of My Sites. Still, perhaps the approach could be used with multiple content DBs..

Comment: Right now im testing a way i found on MS fora by Neil Hodgkinson where i use stsadm backup but with -item "intranet\mysites". This will mean i dont have to iterate all sites: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/7a0100cf-f396-46e6-83e8-06bdb08b432e?prof=required 
Will update if it works, but thanx for the suggestion! :-)

Comment: Let me know how it goes Anders. I know you are using powershell, would love to see what you came up with to make it work.

Comment: Lori: mergecontentdbs was the key! I already **had** all in the same content db, that was the problem! I wanted to filter out all personal sites from the intranet content db & move them into another db in another webapp running my site host. I talked to Todd Klindt who also said mergecontentdbs was the key to splitting up the db using the stsadm command enumsites to feed it xml as described here http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=53
The xml is trimmed to contain only mysites. After that i moved the db from one webapp to another using deletecontentdb and addcontentdb.

Comment: After doing that i only needed to do a createsite command to add the my sites host, and i was up and running with my sites on seperate webapp :-)